# Remove multiple selected classes in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<table id="flex_home" style="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tbody>
<tr class="trSelected"><td align="center" style="display: none;"><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;"></td></tr>
<tr class="trSelected"><td align="center" style="display: none;"><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;"></td></tr>
<tr class="trSelected"><td align="center" style="display: none;"><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="display: none;"><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;"></td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

If i click the tr `selected` class to be added and if i click the another tr the `trselected` to be removed and for which one i selected i need to be have `trselected`

**Jquery**

```
$('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
$(this).removeClass('trselected');
$(this).addClass('trselected');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
 $('.trselected').removeClass('trselected');
 $(this).addClass('trselected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one table on the screen, and want to allow selecting one row in each, you need to remove the class from just the rows in the current table:

```
$('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('trselected');
    $(this).addClass('trselected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in **one line**

```
  $('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
  $('table > tbody >  tr').
   removeClass('trselected').filter(this).addClass("trselected");
  });
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
$('table > tbody > tr').removeClass('trselected').filter(this).addClass("trselected");
 
});
```

```css
.trselected{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="flex_home" style="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tbody>
<tr class="trSelected"><td align="center" ><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">aaa</td></tr>
<tr class="trSelected"><td align="center" ><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">aaa</td></tr>
<tr class="trSelected"><td align="center" ><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">aaaa</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="display: none;"><div style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">aaa</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
$('table > tbody > tr').removeClass('trselected');
$(this).addClass('trselected');
});
```